# Probability of identifying beers

Tags: probability

10 beers. I taste one at a time and guess which beer it is out of a list of ten beers. I can change the selection as the session proceeds.

What is the probability of correctly identifying *n* beers?

I figure that the total permutations is 10!. So, to select one random permutation would give a probability of 1 in 10!.

But, it seems more complicated, because if my first choice is incorrect, then I must certainly have another incorrect choice somewhere else.

Comment: There is a probability 1 of this being delicious.

Comment: After $n>8$, probability drops to $-0.3$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right for the chance to get then all right. To get $k$ right, you have $10 \choose k$ ways to choose the right ones, then need a derangement of the remaining $10-k$ of which there are rounded $\frac {(10-k)!}e$